# Kendo Dropdown with Angular 4

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I am having issues trying to present data to a dropdown list using Kendo UI for angular 4. I have a few things going on here and would be great help if I could see where I am going wrong.

First I have my api call which is returning a list of "name" and "number" for example:

```
{
"name": "Fun Company",
"number": 9
},
{
"name": "Sad Company",
"number": 10
},
```

My service looks like

```
@Injectable()
export class MembersListService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getMembersList(): Observable<MemembersList> {
    return this.http.get('Filtering/Members')
      .map(response => <MemembersList>response.json());
  }
}
```

My component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'foo'
  templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
})
export class fooComponent implements OnInit {
  getMembersList: MemembersList;
  constructor(
    private title: Title,
    private membersListService: MembersListService,
  ) {
    // page title
    this.title.setTitle('FooCompany| Foo Page');
   }

  ngOnInit() {

    // Member List
    this.getMembersList = new MemembersList();
    this.membersListService.getMembersList().subscribe(res => this.getMembersList = res);            
  }    
}
```

MemberList class is

```
export class MemembersList{
  name: string;
  number: number;
}
```

html looks like

```
      <kendo-dropdownlist
        [data]="getMembersList"
        textField="name"
        valueField="number"
        [valuePrimitive]="true"
      >
      </kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but chances are you use an async pipe and a Subject or Observable or something for `getMembersList`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, what if I was just do to a dropdown without using kendo.

Comment: `getMembersList` is not "static". Its value is changing. So changes are it should be an observable (eg `BehaviorSubject`) and you should be publishing values to it, and subscribers like the drop down can know that the values are likely to change by using an async pipe.

Comment: so in this case I should be changing my service to something like this?




getMembersList(): BehaviorSubject<MemembersList> {
    return this.http.get('Filtering/Members')
      .map(response => <MemembersList>response.json());

Comment: textField="name" should be [textField]="'name'" and valueField="number" should be [valueField]="'number'"

Comment: Note the single quotes inside the double.  That is to ensure they are evaluated as variable names.

Comment: @jbrown no, in this case `textField` and `valueField` is a string input. So `[textField]="'name'"` equals `textField="name"`, and both options are valid.

Comment: alright Kendo aside. Can anyone just show by how you would do a basic dropdown using the code above?

Comment: @AlexD is `getMembersList` an Observable or an array?

Comment: in the service.ts I have it as getMembersList(): Observable<MemembersList> {

Answer (score 0):

Kendo Dropdownlist requires an Array of objects or primitive data (Data attribute)

your getMembersList member variable is a single object. Convert it to an array of MembersList and it should be ok

see [Data Binding in Kendo DropDown list](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/data-binding/)